# InDesign GREP is not searching [any] styles

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep, character-styles

I'm troubleshooting one of my book designer's files and I can't seem to wrap my head around what's going on.

She reached out to me that her GREP was not picking up characters she was searching for, even though she could see them.

Looking into it, I noticed that I had to specify the exact Character and Paragraph style applied to the character in order for GREP to pick it up. Setting them to [any] was not pulling any results.

Has anyone experienced this and know why this would happen?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without more info. Are you sure that *Find Format* is cleared when you search? Does it happen with every character or only certain characters? Does it happen if you search using *Text* instead of *GREP*? Can you reproduce the problem in another document? If for example you copy the text to another document.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a bug that Adobe posted a fix for!

GREP was failing to search forward in documents with over 50k words

https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/search-issue-in-long-documents.html